# Is that possible to get yarn application status from AWS EMR Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

**Context**

I run spark applications on an Amazon EMR cluster.

These applications are orchestrated by Yarn.

From AWS Console, I am able to get YARN application status using the `Application History` tab of the cluster's detail page. (cf. [View Application History](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-cluster-application-history.html))
[image]

**Expectation / Question**

I would like to get the same information (application status) but from a java or scala program.

So, is it possible to get yarn application status from AWS EMR Java SDK ?

In my application, I manage some EMR object instance like:

- [AmazonElasticMapReduceClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.html)
- [Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/model/Cluster.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution to this? I have been trying to find an answer to this as well, but with no luck :-(

Comment: Hi @mywoodstock, unfortunately, it seems that nothing exist in AWS SDK to do this. However, you can use `YarnClient` to directly dialogue with the Yarn Resource Manager. (Some ports need to be opened on your emr master node)

Comment: Yep, you can use YARN REST APIs to learn application status once you have SSH tunneling open to EMR master node IP - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_API.

Comment: I am also trying to find a solution to this.  But I am trying to get the total duration for all the executors in the application.  The YarnClient idea won't work for me, because the cluster is not longer running.  But information is inside AWS somewhere, as I can see if in the web UI with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this because i was looking for a way to get the job status via EMRs "steps" api...but if you're looking to get it via yarn directly here is some sample code:

```
object DataLoad {
  private def getJsonField(json: JValue, key: String): Option[String] = {
    val value = (json \ key)
    value match {
      case jval: JValue => Some(jval.values.toString)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  def load(logger: Logger, hiveDatabase: String, hiveTable: String, dw_table_name: String): Unit = {
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load
    val yarnResourceManager = conf.getString("app.yarnResourceManager")
    val sparkExecutors = conf.getString("app.sparkExecutors")
    val sparkHome = conf.getString("app.sparkHome")
    val sparkAppJar = conf.getString("app.sparkAppJar")
    val sparkMainClass = conf.getString("app.sparkMainClass")
    val sparkMaster = conf.getString("app.sparkMaster")
    val sparkDriverMemory = conf.getString("app.sparkDriverMemory")
    val sparkExecutorMemory = conf.getString("app.sparkExecutorMemory")
    var destination = ""
    if(dw_table_name.contains("s3a://")){
      destination = "s3"
    }
    else
      {
        destination = "sql"
      }
  val spark = new SparkLauncher()
    .setSparkHome(sparkHome)
    .setAppResource(sparkAppJar)
    .setMainClass(sparkMainClass)
    .setMaster(sparkMaster)
    .addAppArgs(hiveDatabase)
    .addAppArgs(hiveTable)
    .addAppArgs(destination)
    .setVerbose(false)
    .setConf("spark.driver.memory", sparkDriverMemory)
    .setConf("spark.executor.memory", sparkExecutorMemory)
    .setConf("spark.executor.cores", sparkExecutors)
    .setConf("spark.executor.instances", sparkExecutors)
    .setConf("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "5g")
    .setConf("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "144000")
    .setConf("spark.network.timeout", "144000")
    .startApplication()

  var unknownCounter = 0
  while(!spark.getState.isFinal) {
    println(spark.getState.toString)
    Thread.sleep(10000)

    if(unknownCounter > 3000){
      throw new IllegalStateException("Spark Job Failed, timeout expired 8 hours")
    }
    unknownCounter += 1
  }
    println(spark.getState.toString)
    val appId: String = spark.getAppId
    println(s"appId: $appId")
    var finalState = ""
    var i = 0
    while(i < 5){
      val response = Http(s"http://$yarnResourceManager/ws/v1/cluster/apps/$appId/").asString
      if(response.code.toString.startsWith("2"))
      {
        val json = parse(response.body)
        finalState = getJsonField(json \ "app","finalStatus").getOrElse("")
        i = 55
      }
      else {
        i = i+1
      }
    }
    if(finalState.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCEEDED")){
      println("SPARK JOB SUCCEEDED")
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Spark Job Failed")
    }
  }
}
```